# Using watch command with "echo -e"

Tags: linux, bash, echo, watch

I want to monitor rows of a dynamic file and I use `watch` command for this. I have 2 files: `test-status` and `iplist_test`. I control something in `iplist_test` and I type this output to `test-status`. `iplist_test` file has 150 rows and I want to see a result like `14/150` or `25/150` etc. I use the following command for this:

```
watch -n .1 echo -e "$(cat test-status | wc -l)\/$(cat iplist_test | wc -l)"
```

The command does not work like a `watch` command, it is static. I refresh manually for live results. What's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is static because `$()` is resolved by your shell before `watch` starts.

Quoting with `''` should help. Single quotes prevent expansion, this way `$()` will be passed literally to `watch`, then parsed every time:

```
watch -n .1 'echo -e "$(cat test-status | wc -l)/$(cat iplist_test | wc -l)"'
```

Also you misuse `cat`. This should work without any unnecessary `cat` processes:

```
watch -n .1 'echo -e "$(<test-status wc -l)/$(<iplist_test wc -l)"'
```

If there are single-quotes already in the command you want to watch then see this: [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)