# How to execute complex command line over ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I sometimes want to get the env of a docker container running on a remote host. To do this I log into the host:

```
ssh kramer65@123.456.789.10
```

and then I run this command:

```
sudo docker exec -it `sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}'` env
```

I now want to do this in one command (do it more than 3 times and I want to automate it.. :-) ).

This works:

```
 ssh -t kramer65@123.456.789.10 sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername
```

but when I do this

```
ssh -t kramer65@123.456.789.10 sudo docker exec -it `sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}'` env
```

I get

```
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container
Connection to 123.456.789.10 closed.
```

Does anybody know how I can get this running?

Comment: You need to think about where (local/remote) stuff is executing.

Comment: @DanielB - Aha! You're saying that `sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}'` is running locally before the command is sent over ssh. Good point. But how can I send that code to the server to be executed there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### General observations

There are some keywords in Bash that affect parsing what's after them, e.g. `[[`. But `ssh` is not one of them, it's a regular command. This means that:

- The whole `ssh …` line is normally parsed by your *local* shell; characters like `|`, `;`, `*`, `"`, `$` or space mean something to the shell, they won't get to `ssh`, unless you quote or escape them (with few exceptions, e.g. sole `$` as a separate word is not special). This is the first level of parsing and interpreting.
- Whatever arguments get to `ssh` (or any other regular command) after the shell does its job, they are just arguments, strings. It's now the tool's job to interpret them. This is the second level.

In case of `ssh` some (zero, one or more) of its command line arguments are interpreted as a command to be run on the server side. In general `ssh` is able to build a command from many arguments. The effect is as if you invoked something like this on the server:

```
"$SHELL" -c "$command_line_built_by_ssh"
```

<sup>(I'm not claiming it's *exactly* like this, but it's certainly close enough to understand what happens. I wrote it as if it was invoked in a shell, so it looks familiar; but in fact there is no shell yet. And there is no `$command_line…` as a variable, I'm just using this name to refer to some string for the purpose of this answer.)</sup>

Then `$SHELL` on the server parses `$command_line…` on its own. This is the third level.

---

#### Specific observations

The command that failed

> ```
> ssh -t kramer65@123.456.789.10 sudo docker exec -it `sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}'` env
> ```

<strike>failed because `123.456.789.10` is not a valid IP address.</strike>

<sup>OK, I understand `123.456.789.10` is a placeholder, still it's not valid. :)</sup>

The command failed because it executed `sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}'` locally. The output was probably empty. Then `$command_line_built_by_ssh` was far from what you wanted.

Note `ssh … | grep mycontainername` run `grep` locally (you might or might not be aware of this).

---

#### Discussion

To be in control of what the remote shell will get as `$command_line_built_by_ssh`, you need to understand, predict and mastermind the parsing and interpreting that happens before. You need to craft your local command, so *after* the local shell and `ssh` digest it, it becomes the exact `$command_line…` you want to execute on the remote side.

It may be quite complicated if you actually want your local shell to expand or substitute anything before the result gets to `ssh`. Your case is simpler because you already have the verbatim string you want as `$command_line_built_by_ssh`. The string is:

```
sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}') env
```

Notes:

- I used command substitution in a form of `$()`, not backticks. There are [reasons to prefer `$()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).
- I don't know `docker` at all, I cannot tell if your `$(…)` should be double-quoted. In general [not quoting is almost always bad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Ask yourself what happens when the substitution returns multiple words (i.e. multiple lines enter `awk`). This is a different issue (if ever an issue in this case) and I won't address it in this answer.

To protect everything from being expanded/interpreted by the local shell, you need to properly quote or escape (with `\`) all characters that can trigger expansion or can be interpreted. In this case quote `$`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `;`, `{`, `}`, `'` and (maybe or optionally) spaces.

I said "maybe or optionally quote or escape spaces" because of how `ssh … some command` works. If it finds two or more arguments that it interprets as code to be run on the server, it will concatenate them, adding single spaces in between. This is how `$command_line_built_by_ssh` is built. If you neither quote nor escape spaces in what looks like code for the remote shell, then the local shell will consume spaces (and tabs) while splitting words, then `ssh` will add spaces. The result may be not exactly what you want if there are tabs or multiple consecutive spaces. For example:

```
ssh user@server echo a     b
```

`ssh` gets `user@server`, `echo`, `a`, `b`. The remote command will be `echo a b` and `echo` there will get `a`, `b`. It will print `a b`.

Then this:

```
ssh user@server 'echo a     b'
```

`ssh` gets `user@server`, `echo a     b`. The remote command will be `echo a     b` and `echo` there will get `a`, `b`. It will print `a b`.

And finally this:

```
ssh user@server 'echo "a     b"'
```

`ssh` gets `user@server`, `echo "a     b"`. The remote command will be `echo "a     b"` and `echo` there will get `a     b`. It will print `a     b`.

The conclusion is you should quote in the context of the local shell and *separately* in the context of the remote shell. Keep in mind that when it comes to expanding things by a shell, [the outer quotes matter](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).

---

#### Solution

Putting all this information together (and still assuming you want to protect *everything* from being expanded/interpreted by the local shell), I advise as follows:

- Quote or escape.
- Prefer *quoting* over escaping because a single pair of quotes can protect many characters, while a single `\` protects one character only. You will most likely need many backslashes to protect everything; often the same result can be achieved with just one pair of quotes.
- Prefer *single-quotes* (`'`), they can protect everything but `'`. On the other hand double-quotes (`"`) can protect `'` but not `$` nor `"` (nor `\` sometimes, nor `!` sometimes in Bash), unless `$` and such are escaped as well (i.e. escaped *and* quoted, i.e. escaped within double-quotes; except `!` [which is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33340/108618) [troublesome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565028/108618)).
- Prefer providing command(s) as a *single* argument to `ssh`.

This leads to the following procedure:

1. Prepare a verbatim command you want to run on the remote side.
2. Replace every `'` with `'"'"'` or with `'\''` (you can choose independently for each `'`).
3. Embrace the whole resulting string with single-quotes.
4. Add `ssh …` in front.

Your verbatim command is:

```
sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '{print $1;}') env
```

The procedure results in:

```
ssh -t user@server 'sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps | grep mycontainername | awk '\''{print $1;}'\'') env'
# single-quoted     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^
# escaped                                                                                ^              ^
```

Note the procedure may or may not lead to the shortest possible string. With insight one can sometimes "optimize" the string. But the procedure is quite [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and totally reliable. If only you know you want to protect everything from being expanded/interpreted by the local shell, the procedure itself requires no further insight at all.

---

#### Automation

In fact the procedure can be automated. There are tools that can add quotes to a string and properly preserve existing quotes. Bash itself is such tool. [This answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1531396/432690) provides a way to do this with a keystroke in Bash. A possible solution adjusted to your case is:

1. In your local shell define the following custom function and binding:

   ```
    _prepend_ssh() { READLINE_LINE="ssh  ${READLINE_LINE@Q}"; READLINE_POINT=4; }
    bind -x '"\C-x\C-h":_prepend_ssh'
   ```
2. Still in your local shell type (or paste) the command you want to run in the remote shell; do not execute. The command should be *exactly* as you want it to be in the remote shell.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. The local shell will take care of quoting. It will also add `ssh` in front and place the cursor just after.
4. Add (type) missing arguments (e.g. `-t user@server`). For your convenience the cursor is already in the right position to do this.
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

#### Alternatives

There is another way to pass verbatim commands to a remote shell. In some cases you can *pipe* them via `ssh`. Let's assume the remote command line should be:

```
echo "$PATH"; date
```

We could proceed like above, add single-quotes and run locally like this:

```
ssh user@server 'echo "$PATH"; date'
```

The example is simple but in general adding quotes is not always that easy. Alternatively we can pipe the command like this (the first `echo` for simplicity; [`printf` is better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)):

```
echo 'echo "$PATH"; date' | ssh user@server bash
```

which still requires these single-quotes. But if you have the command(s) in a file, then:

```
<file ssh user@server bash
```

Or even without any file ([here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents)):

```
ssh user@server bash <<'EOF'
echo "$PATH"
date
EOF
```

(Note the quotes in `<<'EOF'` prevent `$PATH` from being expanded locally.)

Advantages:

- You can easily pass multi-line commands/snippets/scripts (I split `echo … ; date` just to show this).
- No additional layer of quoting required.
- You can explicitly choose a remote interpreter which doesn't have to be a shell (e.g. `bash` or `zsh`, or `python`).

Disadvantages:

- You should explicitly specify a remote interpreter, otherwise the default *login* shell will be spawned, message of the day printed maybe. You can still use the default shell as a non-login shell by specifying properly quoted `exec "$SHELL"` (the line will be like `ssh … 'exec "$SHELL"' <<'EOF'`).
- Standard input of `ssh` is not a terminal, so you cannot use `-t` (this is why I didn't use your original command as an example).
- The commands get to the remote interpreter (`bash` in the example) via its standard input. Possible problems:

  - Child processes (or builtins) will use the same stdin. If any of them reads from its stdin then it will read the same stream, possibly it will read the next command(s) destined for the interpreter. This behavior can be suppressed or even creatively (ab)used, I won't elaborate though.
  - You cannot easily use this channel to pipe anything else.

Comment: Strongly concur and wish I could +2, except: for piping/redirecting input, you only need to explicitly specify a shell if the default one (from user's passwd entry, not $SHELL) can't handle the commands you send. It's fairly easy to write commands portable across ksh/dash/bash/zsh, but harder for others like (t)csh.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 (1) One may not explicitly specify a shell (a command in general) but then the default *login* shell is spawned; this can make a difference. Additionally some systems are configured to print message of the day upon login, it will litter the output. (2) `$SHELL` is (or should be) obtained [from user's passwd entry or so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277949/108618) anyway.

Comment: It took me a while to fully comprehend this answer, but wow. Reads like a piece of art. Thank you!

Comment: I would buy you a beer if I could. Instead, here's an upvote!

Comment: man, i love you. This is one of the best answers i ever read to any question at all, at least at stack* :)