# Changing a field value conditionally using awk

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, awk

I have a below values in file.

```
user1 India GJ 1000 IT contractor
user2 Ind GJ 1001 HR contractor
user3 USA CA 1002 R&D hourly
user4 India TN 1003 R&D fte
user5 Ind KA 1004 FE fte
user6 In GJ 2345 HR hourly
```

Need to match 3rd column and update 2nd column. I am able to do using below command.

```
awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {$2="IN"} {print}' filename
```

output for above command is

```
user1 IN GJ 1000 IT contractor
user2 IN GJ 1001 HR contractor
user3 USA CA 1002 R&D hourly
user4 IN TN 1003 R&D fte
user1 IN GJ 1000 IT contractor
user5 IN KA 1004 FE fte
user6 IN GJ 2345 HR hourly
```

But the same does not work when I run over ssh

```
ssh -q server1 "awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {\$2="IN"} {print}" filename
```

The output over SSH

```
user1  GJ 1000 IT contractor
user2  GJ 1001 HR contractor
user3 USA CA 1002 R&D hourly
user4  TN 1003 R&D fte
user1  GJ 1000 IT contractor
user5  KA 1004 FE fte
user6  GJ 2345 HR hourly
```

not sure what I am missing and why its not working our SSH. I am open for any other solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is incoherent. The `ssh` command (executed exactly as it is posted) will yield `Unexpected EOF while looking for matching '` (strictly: the shell on the server will yield this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What happened

Your command

> ```
> ssh -q server1 "awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {\$2="IN"} {print}'" filename
> ```

<sup>(note I added the missing `'`; without it `awk` would not run at all)</sup>

does not do what you want because the local shell removes all the double-quotes. Look:

```
          ssh -q server1 "awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {\$2="IN"} {print}'" filename
quoted:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^
unquoted: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  ^^            ^^^^^^^^^
```

In effect `ssh` gets `awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {$2=IN} {print}'` and `filename` (as separate arguments). It builds the following command to run on the remote side:

```
awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {$2=IN} {print}' filename
```

This means `awk` executes

```
/GJ|TN|KA/ {$2=IN} {print}
```

where `IN` is not considered to be a string, it's a variable in `awk`. The variable is empty.

---

#### Solution

To make the "inner" double-quotes survive and get to the remote shell (and to `awk` eventually), escape them just like you did with `$`:

```
ssh -q server1 "awk -i inplace '/GJ|TN|KA/ {\$2=\"IN\"} {print}'" filename
```

---

#### More information:

- [**How to execute complex command line over ssh?**](https://superuser.com/q/1533956/432690) Your command is not very complex, still [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690) to the linked question may help because it explains how `ssh` runs commands in general and how to deal with some possible problems.
- You had a command you wanted to provide to `ssh` *without any local expansion*. This is exactly the case the following question is designed to help with: [**How to single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?**](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: Hi Thanks for wonderful explanation. It resolved the issue and also understood my mistake.