# How to pass environment to remote machine when ssh

Tags: ssh

I'd like execute command like this:

```
ssh remote_host export ENV_1=a && echo $ENV_1
```

But it turns out ENV_1 is empty, is there anything I did wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENV_1` is empty because it's `ENV_1` of your local shell. The `&&` in your code is interpreted by your local shell *and* `$ENV_1` gets substituted by your local shell.

`ssh` is smart enough to build a remote command from multiple arguments. Example:

```
ssh remote_host 'echo 1 2'
ssh remote_host 'echo 1' 2
ssh remote_host echo 1 2
```

The remote command will be `echo 1 2` in each case, but it will be built from `echo 1 2` (1 argument) or `echo 1`, `2` (2 arguments) or `echo`, `1`, `2` (3 arguments) respectively. There are more possibilities.

It seems you wanted `export ENV_1=a && echo $ENV_1` to be the remote command. Well, your local shell saw `&&` and interpreted the whole line as `ssh … && echo $ENV_1`.

You should escape or quote `&&` to protect it from the local shell. But if you do nothing more, `$ENV_1` will still be substituted (by an empty string) by the local shell. You also need to escape `$` or single-quote the variable.

The best thing is to quote the entire remote command. You don't want the variable to be expanded locally, so at least `$ENV_1` should be single-quoted. In your desired command there's nothing that shouldn't be single-quoted, you can single-quote the entire remote command. But when it gets to the remote shell, the variable [should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). So this:

```
ssh remote_host 'export ENV_1=a && echo "$ENV_1"'
```

The variable won't be expanded locally because [the outer quotes matter](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690). Locally single-quotes are the outer ones.

You can find broader analysis in my answer to [*How to execute complex command line over ssh?*](https://superuser.com/q/1533956/432690)
If your local shell is Bash then check [*How to single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: Do you know any method to pass envs from .env file through ssh?

Comment: @wieczorek1990 Copy the file to the remote side and handle everything there.