# ssh $targetHost "[[ -z $(grep..." - fails. Why?

Tags: bash, ssh

[edit] per comment #1: more code, less description

Why doesn't this work as expected?
ie: i want to :

- ssh to a bunch of remote hosts in a loop (hence the </dev/null)
- check if a setting is present in (the remote) rc.local (with grep)
- if not then add it (with sed)

fail.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
targetHostList="
pizerocam0
pizerocam1
pizerocam2
pizerocam3
"
while IFS= read -r targetHost;do
    [[ -z $targetHost ]] && continue
    ssh -q $targetHost "[[ -f /etc/rc.local && -z $(grep -o '/usr/bin/tvservice -o' /etc/rc.local) ]] && sudo sed -Ei 's/exit\ 0/\/usr\/bin\/tvservice\ \-o \#\ disable HDMI\n\nexit\ 0/' /etc/rc.local"
done<<<"$targetHostList"
```

Comment: What is expected? `$(grep …)` gets expanded *locally*, apparently it returns an empty string. Depending on where you want to expand it, you should double-quote or single-quote (or escape). After the local shell removes quotes it does interpret, the resulting command string will be interpreted *again* on the remote side. At this point it should contain quotes to be interpreted *there*. So you need at least two levels of quoting/escaping. For now I'm not sure if you want `$()` to work locally. How about `&&`? Is `</dev/null` for `ssh` or for `sudo`? In general: what is expected?

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626511/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] Thanks Kamil! I just needed to see it. Knew it was what I wanted immediately. I'm sure i've done this before and just forgotten how.

SOLVED.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
targetHostList="
pizerocam0
pizerocam1
pizerocam2
pizerocam3
"
while IFS= read -r targetHost;do
    [[ -z $targetHost ]] && continue

ssh -q $targetHost bash <<'EOF'
[[ -f /etc/rc.local && -z $(grep -o '/usr/bin/tvservice -o' /etc/rc.local) ]] && sudo sed -Ei 's/exit\ 0/\/usr\/bin\/tvservice\ \-o \#\ disable HDMI\n\nexit\ 0/' /etc/rc.local
EOF

done<<<"$targetHostList"
```