# How to pass commandline argument to kubectl exec shell when run over ssh

Tags: ssh, kubernetes

How to pass the command like argument when kubectl is run over ssh? -l argument to ls is passed to pod shell if i run without ssh. I tried to escape, put inside quotes etc, but nothing worked.

```
ssh  xxx-a@machine.com  kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- sh -c ls -l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful resources:

- [how `ssh` remote command line arguments get parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414640/108618)
- [how to execute complex command line over SSH](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690)

If you know the exact command you want to execute in the remote shell then you can craft a command for the local shell. I think the command for the remote shell should *not* be:

```
# wrong
kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- sh -c ls -l
```

because it would run `kubectl` that would run `sh -c ls -l`. Try the latter code locally and you will see it doesn't run `ls -l`. This is because `-l` does not belong to the code `sh` is told to run. The code for `sh` should be a *single* option-argument after `-c`; further arguments (if any) are different (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)).

This means ultimately you need a command that in a shell would look like this: `sh -c 'ls -l'`. Your `kubectl exec` will run this if `ls -l` is a
single argument to it. So you need this in the remote shell:

```
kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- sh -c 'ls -l'
# or
kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- sh -c "ls -l"
```

(Let's pick the latter one.) Now you know the exact command you want to execute in the remote shell. Pass it to your local `ssh` as a single argument:

```
ssh xxx-a@machine.com 'kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- sh -c "ls -l"'
```

The outer (single) quotes will be removed by the local shell, but thanks to them `ssh` will get the large code string (`kubectl … "ls -l"`) as a single argument. The code will contain the inner (double) quotes. These will be removed by the remote shell (spawned by the SSH server), but thanks to them `kubectl` will get the small code string (`ls -l`) as a single argument; therefore it will spawn `sh` that will get the code as a single argument.

In this case it doesn't matter which quoting uses single-, which uses double-quotes. What matters is the quote pairs are different (as opposed to e.g. `a "b "c""` where the quotes are not inner and outer, they are two separate pairs with `c` being unquoted).

---

Note different tools digest their arguments and build "code" for the next step differently:

- `ssh` can concatenate multiple arguments to build code for the remote shell (that's why your attempt kinda worked); then the remote shell interprets a single string. When I need to protect things (e.g. quotes) from the local shell (and this is the case here) I prefer to quote the whole code locally and pass it to `ssh` as a single argument; but this is my choice.

  So `ssh` builds one string from one or more arguments.
- `kubectl exec` treats arguments after `--` as an array. In our case it runs `sh` with arguments `-c` and `ls -l` (in your attempt the arguments were `-c`, `ls` and `-l`).

  So `kubectl exec` does not build any string. From the array of arguments it builds an array to execute.
- `sh -c` interprets only one argument after `-c` as shell code. It does not concatenate multiple arguments like `ssh` can.

Imagine `sh -c` as an interface to run code in a local shell; and `ssh …@…` as an interface to run code in a remote shell. They are similar, each spawns a shell that will interpret code written as a single string. Yet they are different, the difference is in how the string is created: `sh -c` takes code from exactly one argument, `ssh` builds code from possibly many arguments. `kubectl exec` is an interface to run an executable in a container. It differs the most from the other two interfaces because it uses its arguments directly as an array.

---

Do you really need `sh -c`? I think in this case

```
ssh xxx-a@machine.com 'kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- ls -l'
```

is enough. Note if you used `"ls -l"` (still inside the single-quoted code) here then `kubectl exec` would try to run an executable named `ls -l` (instead of `ls` with `-l` as an argument). Here you don't want to apply inner quotes to `ls -l`.

OTOH any of these:

```
ssh xxx-a@machine.com kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- ls -l
ssh xxx-a@machine.com kubectl exec -it mypod -n mynamespace -- "ls -l"
ssh xxx-a@machine.com kubectl exec -it "mypod -n mynamespace -- ls" -l
```

will work because `ssh` will build the same string for the remote shell (from different number of different arguments though). The last example is especially bizarre; it locally gathers multiple "final" arguments into one, seemingly braking the logic (I mean `ls` has more to do with `-l` than with `-n`, right?). Nevertheless it works and the reason is the way `ssh` builds one string from many.

`sh -c` is a must in cases where instead of `ls -l` you have anything that truly needs a shell (e.g. a pipeline with `|`, a command with redirections like `>file`, shell syntax like `if`).

---

Your command (or my fixed command) consists of few nested tools. In each step one (the outer) tool digests its arguments somehow and spawns another (the inner) tool on the same or another host somehow. The final conclusion is you need to know all the tools you're using, the ways they parse their arguments and invoke the next tool. Note in our example there is a local shell before `ssh` and there is a remote shell between the SSH daemon on the server and `kubectl`; you need to take each implicit shell into account as well.