# How to pass bash's $@ over ssh accounting for spaces in arguments?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line-arguments, escaping, journalctl

I want to read logs conveniently from my server. I'm trying to write a script that reads output of `journalctl` from my server, applying the parameters I pass to the script to `journalctl` call. I may want to apply various filters, so I want arguments to my script to translate to `journalctl`'s arguments. For example

```
bin/log --since '2 days ago'
```

would run

```
ssh host journalctl --since '2 days ago'
```

I tried this:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
ssh host journalctl "$@"
```

But when I call

```
bin/log --since '2 days ago'
```

I just says:

```
Failed to parse timestamp: 2
```

Ok, we got an argument with spaces that seems to transform to multiple arguments when passed as part of a command over SSH. Then I tried something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
ssh host bash -c 'journalctl autotests "$@"'
```

You can guess that doesn't do what I need.

How the hell do I pass `$@` over ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question: [*How to execute complex command line over ssh*](https://superuser.com/q/1533956/432690) is somewhat related. My answer there concentrates on the case where nothing is expanded locally; you want to expand `$@` locally, it makes things more complicated. Still the linked resource may give you some insight into how these things work.

In your case the easiest way is to use the `Q` operator (see the beginning of [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1531396/432690)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh host "journalctl autotests ${@@Q}"
```

<sup>The above code won't work in pure `sh`, you need (local) `bash`. The "shebang" in your question is `#/usr/bin/env bash`, it's not a shebang, it's just a comment; a shebang should start with `#!`. The above code uses a proper shebang.</sup>

Note if you do:

```
ssh host bash -c "journalctl autotests ${@@Q}"
```

then the shell code on the remote side will lack one level of quotes. If you really need `bash -c` then this is what you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cmd="journalctl autotests ${@@Q}"
ssh host "bash -c ${cmd@Q}"
```

The additional usage of `@Q` gives you the additional level of quoting (or escaping) you need. But in this exact case you most likely don't need `bash -c` at all, the first command I gave you should work.

Comment: One caveat about this: the `@Q` modifier adds bash-compatible quoting/escaping. In some (rather obscure) situations, if the remote shell is something other than bash, it might not parse the quoting/escaping as expected, leading to weird problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I think there is nothing obscure in different shells handling input commands differently, but yeah, there can be a shell on the other end other than bash. I wonder how this whole situation can be handled in fish, for instance.

Comment: @jojman I *think* that it'll work with fish as the remote shell, unless the variable contains control characters (which will make `@Q` use ANSI-C quoting mode, which I think only bash, zsh, and ksh support), or ```\\``` or ```\'``` or ends with ```\``` (which cause trouble because fish interprets ```\\``` and ```\'``` inside single-quoted strings).