# use echo to write to file and include single quotes

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I have the command here

```
doctl compute ssh testdroplet --ssh-command 'echo -e "import http.server\nimport socketserver\nfrom http import HTTPStatus\n\nclass Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):\n    def do_GET(self):\n        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)\n        self.end_headers()\n        self.wfile.write(b'Hello world')\n\nhttpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', 8000), Handler)\nhttpd.serve_forever()" >> web/server.py'
```

which I need to write single quotes into a file. I changed the format to use single quotes outside `echo` because when I used double quotes the single quotes were not written to file (everything except the single quotes was written to file).

Now instead of a working command I get error

```
deploy_server % ./deploy_droplet.sh          
root@142.93.555.190's password: 
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Error: exit status 1
```

How can I successfully write to file but also write in these single quotes? Thank you

Comment: Look into ESCAPEing those quotes.  This is a special char that tells the shell to ignore what you are passing.

Comment: [Hint](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690).

Comment: Note that you have four "layers" of quoting and/or escaping here: quotes/escapes that'll be applied (and removed) by the local shell, quotes/escapes that'll be applied (and removed) by the *remote* shell, escapes that'll be applied (and removed) by `echo -e`, and finally the quotes you want written into the remote file. It might be simpler to base64-encode what you want to put in the file instead of trying to thread your way through that many layers.