# Append a line to the end of the file using ssh, sudo and sed

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, sed

I have an obvious problem with quoting in bash such that I couldn't really solve for a while. Here is a loop with executing a remote command in a sudo-subshell on a remote server via ssh:

```
for HOST in $RUNNER_LIST; do
  ssh -t $HOST "sudo bash -c \"sed -i '$a 10.10.40.29 myhost' /etc/hosts\""
done 2>/dev/null
```

Now, this simple approach, of course, doesn't work. That `$a` gets expanded by the local shell, and since that's an unset variable sed executes the expression `' 10.10.40.29 myhost'`

I've tried out several approaches, and during writing this question, I somehow found out that this worked:

```
ssh -t $HOST "sudo bash -c \"sed -i '"'\$'"a 10.10.40.29 myhost' /etc/hosts\""
```

and using prepended `set -x`, I see that on the remote shell, it's expanded to

```
sudo bash -c 'sed '\''$a 10.10.40.29 myhost'\'' /etc/hosts'
```

I was surprised since my intention was to escape `$`. Instead of it, the quotes got escaped. So I would like to have a clear explanation of how this expansion worked. And maybe there is a way to make this command more readable?

Comment: (1) What is the reason for `bash -c`? Why not `sudo sed …`? (2) [How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: I use `bash -c` in this loop because usually I want to execute a command group as root, for instance `bash -c "yum update -y && reboot"`

Comment: For this case can add a space `sed '$ a blah'` because shell won't treat that as a variable but sed will treat it as a valid command. Or can do `echo 10.1.2.3 name | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts` which doesn't need any `$` _or_ internal quoting.

Answer (score 0):

This  does not really answer your question (I did read your post too quickly, sorry); To properly do what you wanted, you need to doubly escape the `$` (for `sed`, and for `bash`) :

```bsh
for HOST in $RUNNER_LIST; do
  ssh -t $HOST "sudo bash -c \"sed -i '\\\$a 10.10.40.29 myhost' /tmp/hosts\""
done 2>/dev/null
```

Without the `bash -c`, only one level is necessary :

```bsh
for HOST in $RUNNER_LIST; do
  ssh -t $HOST "sudo sed -i '\$a 10.10.40.29 myhost' /tmp/hosts"
done 2>/dev/null
```