# Pipe in argument list of bash function

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm using simple function to make my script more verbose.

```
cmd() {
  echo "[#] $*" >&2
  "$@"
}
```

When calling script with option `-v` all commands goes through `cmd` function:

```
build() {
  cmd yarn webpack --config webpack.prod.js
}

copy_to_server() {
  cmd tar -cf - -C ./dist . | ssh root@mydomain.com tar -xf - -C /path/to/desirable/dir
}

main() {
  build
  copy_to_server
}

main
```

Everything works nice except command with pipe. It even echoed only up to dot before pipe sign. Is there any chance to make it properly work?

Comment: Your `cmd` does not see the pipe symbol and beyond. If `cmd` wasn't there, `tar` wouldn't see the pipe symbol either (would you expect `tar` to see it?). What is the expected output then? Ask yourself if `set -x` is not enough for your "verbose mode", *maybe* you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, now I got this point. Thanks. Really for `cmd` pipe is something that will get its results. By the way, I never read `4.3.1 The Set Builtin` to the paragraph with `-x`. Maybe it will be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

In this piece of code:

> ```
> cmd tar -cf - -C ./dist . | ssh root@mydomain.com tar -xf - -C /path/to/desirable/dir
> ```

`cmd` does not see the pipe symbol and beyond. If `cmd` wasn't there, `tar` wouldn't see the pipe symbol either.

---

#### Out of the box solutions

Do not reinvent the wheel. A shell (not only Bash but any POSIX-like shell) gives you at least two options that resemble what your `cmd` does:

> `-v`
> The shell shall write its input to standard error as it is read.
>
> `-x`
> The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it. […]

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set))</sup>

You enable the options with `set -v` and `set -x`; you disable with `set +v` and `set +x` respectively. You can enable or disable both at once with `set -vx` or `set +vx`.

In case of `set -v`, your pipeline will be printed as-is. `set -x` will print `tar` and `ssh` separately, but it will expand it first; on the other hand iw won't show you redirections. The below script shows these differences (there may be more of them):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -vx
foo=bar
echo "$foo" | wc -c 2>/dev/null
```

The output will be (`# comments` mine):

```
foo=bar                          # from set -v,   to stderr
+ foo=bar                        # from set -x,   to stderr
echo "$foo" | wc -c 2>/dev/null  # from set -v,   to stderr
+ echo bar                       # from set -x,   to stderr
+ wc -c                          # from set -x,   to stderr
4                                # actual output, to stdout
```

Also note `set -v` prints shell code *as it is read*, this results in at least two quirks:

1. Some snippets have to be read at once, e.g. `while … done` or `if … fi` (because there may be redirection(s) after `done` or `fi`), so `set -v` will show each such snippet as a whole, once.
2. A command like `sh -c 'set -v; echo foo'` will "ignore" `set -v` because at the time `set -v` gets executed all the input has already been read. This will also happen if you use a newline instead of `;`; or with `sh -vc 'echo foo'`. In a script `set -v` should work well.

An advantage is you can (possibly conditionally) run `set -v` or `set -x` (or `set -vx`) early in your script and there is no need to modify the rest of the code. A disadvantage is the whole later code (until `set +v` or so) will be affected, while with your `cmd` (if it worked exactly as you wish) you can apply `cmd` to specific lines only.

---

#### Custom solution

I can imagine neither `set -v` nor `set -x` (nor `set -vx`) is exactly what you want. There is a way to make your `cmd` print pipelines like `tar … | ssh …`. Take this function:

```sh
cmd() {
   [ "$debug" = 1 ] && (IFS=' '; printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2)
   eval "$@"
}
```

and use it like this:

```
debug=1
cmd 'tar -cf - -C ./dist . | ssh root@mydomain.com tar -xf - -C /path/to/desirable/dir'
```

With `debug=1` and `debug=something_else` you can turn printing from `cmd` on or off.

But you need to be very careful. I deliberately built `cmd` so it accepts multiple arguments. The support for multiple arguments allows you to simply run:

```
cmd echo foo
```

or

```
cmd echo foo \| wc -c
```

where only `|` needs to be escaped (or quoted). You need to be careful with expansions and quoting though ([even in simple cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332579/108618)). The code is parsed before `cmd` runs and *again* when `eval` runs. So this:

```
foo='$(echo 123456789)'
cmd echo "$foo"
```

will expand `$foo` before `cmd` *and then* `eval` will expand `$(echo 123456789)` and the output will be `123456789`. Note it could be `foo='$(reboot)'`, while by `cmd echo "$foo"` you clearly don't want to reboot.

And while `echo ">very-important-file"` is harmless, `cmd echo ">very-important-file"` will truncate `very-important-file` to zero size. The quotes will be removed before `cmd` runs and they won't appear in what `eval` evaluates, so the command will become `echo >very-important-file`.

A firm way to avoid such mishaps is to use `cmd` with exactly one single-quoted argument. This is especially important if some part (like the `foo` variable) is not under your total control (e.g. it comes from the environment or from `read foo`). A safe usage looks like this:

```
cmd 'echo "$foo"'
```

or

```
cmd 'echo ">very-important-file"'
```

Passing everything as a single-quoted argument complicates quoting in cases when you actually need single-quotes before introducing `cmd`, but since you should prevent expansion at this stage, some additional quoting and/or escaping is inevitable; or else you risk executing the wrong code.

A general procedure to single-quote any string in a shell (even if the string contains single-quotes) is:

- replace every `'` with `'"'"'` or with `'\''`,
- embrace the whole resulting string with single-quotes.

Finally you add `cmd`  in front. The procedure is totally "mechanical", there are no quirks, no exceptions, it requires no further insight, so it can be easily automated ([and Bash itself can do this](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690), but note the linked question is for the command line of interactive Bash and it won't help you when writing scripts in a text editor; a powerful enough editor should allow you to automate this in its own way though).

Now you can pass any snippet to `cmd`, no matter if it contains `|`, `&&`, `[[`, whole `if` clause, newlines, redirections or whatever. Examples:

```
cmd 'echo foo && echo bar; echo "$PATH" | dd conv=ucase 2>/dev/null'
```

```
cmd '
echo '\''$PATH'\'' is
echo "$PATH"
'
```

---

Inside `cmd` we use `$*` and `$@`. It's true `$*` uses the first character of `$IFS`, therefore we fix `IFS` where we use `$*` with `printf`; but using `$*` with `eval` while similarly fixing `IFS` would be wrong because it would affect `IFS` for the shell code we want to execute; fortunately `eval` works fine with `"$@"`. Our `cmd` should work with any `IFS`. Example:

```
IFS=.
cmd read a b c
```

Provide `1.2.3`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then check (with `echo "$a"`) if `$a` is `1`. (Note if you do this in an interactive shell then the modified `IFS` will stay.)

`IFS=. cmd read a b c` and `cmd IFS=. read a b c` should also work as expected. In neither case the modified `IFS` will break our `cmd`. Note in these examples I deliberately passed multiple arguments to `cmd` to truly test if `$*`, `$@` and the whole function behave well.

---

#### Summary

Try `set -v` and/or `set -x`, maybe they will be enough for you. If not, use our custom `cmd`, but then you *really* need to quote and/or escape right.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such detailed answer. I've never dived so deeply into this topic. In any case, I tried `set -v` and think that it's enough for my goals. But I'll test your solution just to understand how `bash` works.